# plotting a projectile motion based on user's input

Tags: python

I am doing a projectile motion formula but I am having trouble from the user's input on how to do it. Just based on simple formula of projectile motion, I need to have a graph for it. This is my code:

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

print("Xt = V0 * (cos(Θ)) * t)") #formula
print("Yt = Y0 + (V0 * t * sin(Θ)) - (0.5 * (g * (t)²))") #formula
g = 9.8
v = float(input("What is the velocity? "))
theta = int(input("What is the value of Θ? "))
t = float(input("What is the value of time? "))

for i in theta: #error here since my theta is not iterable. 
    x1 = []
    y1 = []
    for k in t:
        x = ((v*k)*np.cos(i))
        y = ((v*k)*np.sin(i))-((0.5*g)*(k**2))
        x1.append(x)
        y1.append(y)
p = [i for i, j in enumerate(y1) if j < 0] # Don't fall through the floor                          
for i in sorted(p, reverse = True):
    del x1[i]
    del y1[i]

plt.plot(x1, y1) 
plt.show()
```

Comment: Share the errors you are facing

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish I edited. I am having an error from the iterable. I don't know how can I show the graph of it since I am based on user's input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

You can't have time as a float, i've changed it to an `int` Is it okay for you? Tell me if its not

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

print("Xt = V0 * (cos(Θ)) * t)") #formula
print("Yt = Y0 + (V0 * t * sin(Θ)) - (0.5 * (g * (t)²))") #formula
g = 9.8
v = float(input("What is the velocity? "))
theta = int(input("What is the value of Θ? "))
t = int(input("What is the value of time? (in seconds) "))

for i in range(theta):
    x1 = []
    y1 = []
    for k in range(t):
        x = ((v*k)*np.cos(i))
        y = ((v*k)*np.sin(i))-((0.5*g)*(k**2))
        x1.append(x)
        y1.append(y)

plt.plot(x1, y1) 
plt.show()

p = [i for i, j in enumerate(y1) if j < 0] # Don't fall through the floor                          
for i in sorted(p, reverse = True):
    del x1[i]
    del y1[i]
```

Sample Input:

v = 2

0 = 35

t = 20

Output:

[image]

Tell me if this is not what you want...

Comment: This is okay for me, but can I ask? Why I can't make the time as float?

Comment: i just made the time variable into an integer to run it inside ```range()``` (which only accepts ```int```) and also, the decimal value of the time variable is not gonna change the trajectory path at any slightest, so i considered it as an integer, is it helpful?

Comment: Oh. I got it! This is helpful.